# Moment.js: only certain localizations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, momentjs

I am looking for a way to include [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) with a localization (german in my case), but not with all other localizations (the 40kb minified version), to keep it slim.  Is it possible to exclude all other localizations but one specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `moment.js` docs : Loading locales in the browser just requires you to include the locale files.

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="locale/fr.js"></script>
<script src="locale/pt.js"></script>
<script>
   moment.locale('fr');  // Set the default/global locale
  // ...
</script>
```

Also if you desire, you can build a minified moment.js version bundled with the locale of your choice.

```
grunt embedLocales --embedLocales de
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in comments and according to the [contribution guide](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md#grunt-tasks) running this command :

```
grunt transpile:fr,ru
```

Will result in custom locale bundles `moment-with-locales.custom.js` and `locales.custom.js` inside `build/umd/min` containing just French and Russian.

Comment: Perhaps the grunt file changed since December, but I had to write `grunt release --embedLocales de`. `grunt embedLocales ...` throws an error.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md):
`grunt transpile:fr,ru` Build custom locale bundles moment-with-locales.custom.js and locales.custom.js inside build/umd/min containing just French and Russian.